# Is there a wchar_t version for asprintf?

Tags: c, wchar-t, printf

I need a C function which returns the final length of a formatted string so I can properly allocate the target string, rather than calculate the length myself. There is `snprintf` which does just this upon inability to write the entire string, but unfortunately there is no wide char alternative for it.

`swprintf` returns -1 in case of error, not the needed length (why not the same behaviour ?!?)

The title mentioned `asprintf` seems to be of no help also, as it provides a non-wide version only.

`_vscwprintf` can be used on windows, but I need a crossplatform, standard version, or at least a Linux version and I'll #ifdef the code.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POSIX 2008 added the [`open_wmemstream`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html) function which, along with `vfwprintf`, does exactly what you need. It was formerly a GNU extension, so it's been available on GNU systems for a long time.

This can easily be used to construct a `awprintf` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This hack is nice and it actually works.I still don't understand why things so simple like `awprintf` don't make it to the standard when more complicated features are added.

Comment: Probably because the standard in question is POSIX and almost nobody coding for POSIX systems uses `wchar_t` except when they have to...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [`swprintf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/swprintf).  Note that despite its name, `swprintf` is the wide-character equivalent of `snprintf`, *not* `sprintf`, in that it takes a buffer size as its second parameter; there is (fortunately) no wide-character version that does not take a buffer size.

Also, since it returns -1 on overflow, you'll have to get the total length of the string some other way.  The only really portable way to do this is to start with a buffer of some size, try formatting and see if it's big enough, and if not, increase the size and reformat until it is big enough.  This is not very efficient, as you can imagine.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I had thought of in the first place, I just hoped there is a better solution already implemented. Finally, I think I will have to compute the length myself, which seems error prone on the general case, but I'll make sure to be thorough.

Comment: There is a better way; see my answer. You might want to fallback to Adam's solution for pre-POSIX-2008 systems.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there seems to be a fundamental flaw in your expectations. Adding these up:

1. Windows has what you want
2. Linux has a non-wide variant (`asprintf` is not in any standard, but purely a GNU extension for Linux and *BSD).
3. POSIX defines everything string/file related as a null-terminated `char*` array, which explains the lack of wide versions of pretty much any POSIX function.
4. On top of 2, 3, and 4, all modern Linux distros are UTF-8 based, meaning that non-wide versions are what is "meant to be used".

Adding these up gives: why would you need an something like this? Surely you're not using `wchar_t`s on Unix are you `;)`. If you are, there's still two options: switch to a `tchar`-like solution (platform dependent typedef) or completely switch to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I kinda have to use wchar_t and switching to UTF-8 might be too time costly.

Comment: @gheorghe1800: scrap wchar_t and use [UTF-8](http://utf8everywhere.org/). If you had followed it, this question wouldn't have arose.